# Java file.delete() returns false only

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, bufferedreader

I want to delete "db.txt" (programPath[1]). I checked the code an I closed all Scanners and BufferedReaders. When I try to delete , it returns false. I tried to debug my code with VisualVM, but I could not find anything wrong. I used that file in 2 methods. For better visibility I marked the place when I opened and closed the file (TODO). This is the
first method:

```
public static void changePassword(boolean isLogged, String[] programPath, File db) {
    if (!isLogged) {
        login(isLogged, programPath, db);
    }

    File tempFile = new File(programPath[2]);
    File tempDbFile = new File(programPath[0] + File.separator + "tempDb.txt");


    try {
        BufferedReader tempFileScanner = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(tempFile));
        BufferedReader dbScanner = new BufferedReader((new FileReader(db))); // TODO db open
        //Scanner dbScanner = new Scanner(db);
        FileWriter tempDbWriter = new FileWriter(tempDbFile);

        if (!tempDbFile.exists()){
            try {
                tempDbFile.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("created");

        }


        String[] lineToRemove = tempFileScanner.readLine().split("\\:");
        tempFileScanner.close();

        String line;
        while((line = dbScanner.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println("Line: " + line);
            System.out.println("Line to remove: " + lineToRemove[0] + ":" + lineToRemove[1]);

            if(line.equals(lineToRemove[0] + ":" + lineToRemove[1])){
                tempDbWriter.write(lineToRemove[0] + ":" + newPass + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
                continue;
            }
            tempDbWriter.write(line + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
            System.out.println("Written: " + line);
        }
        tempDbWriter.close();
        dbScanner.close(); // TODO db closed

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(db.delete()){
        System.out.println("File deleted");
    } else if(!db.delete()){
        System.out.println("File not deleted. W H Y ?");
    }


}
```

2nd method:

```
public static boolean checkCredentials(String[] programPath, File db){

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); // for getting user input

    System.out.println("Please insert your card number: ");
    String cardNr = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Please insert your PIN: ");
    String pin = scan.nextLine();

    try {
        Scanner dbScanner = new Scanner(db); // TODO db open
        //now read the file line by line...

        while (dbScanner.hasNextLine()) {
            String[] line = dbScanner.nextLine().split("\\:");
            System.out.println("CardNr: " + cardNr);
            System.out.println("Pin: " + pin);

            if(line[0].equals(cardNr) && line[1].equals(pin)) {
                String[] loggedInAs = {line[0], line[1]};
                tempFile.createTempFile(programPath, loggedInAs);
                return true;
            }
        }
        dbScanner.close(); // TODO db close
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
        //handle this
    }

    return false;

}
```

Can someone explain what I did wrong? Or how can I see where is opened?

P.S. I have the rights to delete/modify the files

Comment: First, check if you have permission to delete the file.

Comment: I have. Another class is deleting a file and I don't have problems. I edited the question.

Comment: In which line did you write file.delete() sorry I can't seem to find it.

Comment: first method, on the last lines. There is a if statement; That statement checks if the file is deleted.

Comment: Can you make a minimal example?

Comment: I don't understand what you want. What kind of example?

Comment: I made a new Project and I ran the file.delete() function. It worked without any problems... The problem is in this part of code. I'm not asking for debugging. All I asked is how can I see where my file is opened and why it returns false even if I have the rights

Comment: I think I understand your problem.  You're saying that `new FileReader(db)` succeeds, you close the result of that call, and yet `db.delete()` fails by returning `false`.  Have I got it right? - This is not happening only when an exception is thrown, right?  It makes sense that the file wouldn't be deletable if an exception is thrown.  You should put your `close()` call in a `finally` block or use a try-with-resources block.

Answer (score 1):

Many, many things. Mostly, you're writing java code as if it's still 1992.

1. Use try-with-resources. You are not safely closing resources (you say you are, but your code snippet indicates this is not the case). When you write `new FileReader()`, that is the exact point where you need [A] save what that returns (you don't, you pass it through to the constructor of BufferedReader), and [B] close that thing **in a finally block**. Or, better yet, just use try with resources. I'm not going to show you how yet, I'll combine multiple points in a single snippet later. **This is the most likely cause of your problem**.
2. Using the old API. The File.delete API just returns true or false and tells you nothing. Therefore, use the new API from the `java.nio.file` package. Unlike the old API, it doesn't return a boolean at all (it throws an exception, like proper API design dictates: You asked for a delete, if that is not an option, an exception should be thrown), and because it does that, this exception contains all sorts of details about WHY it can't delete. That'll answer your questions. For example, maybe you get the error: "IOException: Read-only filesystem". Now you know.
3. deplorable exception handling. No matter how often it occurs in examples, `catch (Something e) {e.printStackTrace();}` is no good and is **NEVER** acceptable in code. The right 'I just do not want to deal with this approach' is always to just add a `throws` clause to your method (remember: `psv main` can and should be written to `throws Exception`!), and if that's not an option, the 'just go away, compiler' take on a catch block is not `e.printStackTrace`, it's: `throw new RuntimeException("uncaught", e);`. This gives you way more debug information than e.printStackTrace does, and conveniently stops the 'snowball of error' that e.printStackTrace causes (just e.printStackTrace will print the error and then continues running code. That code is extremely likely to also fail, because the variables aren't in the expected state. If all code you write just catches exceptions, prints, and continues, then a single error will cause a cascade of further, completely irrelevant errors, resulting in 1 problem printing out 183 separate stack traces, and *all of them* except the first are complete red herrings. This is all prevented with proper error handling, and is also all prevented with more sane defaults (those being: add `throws`, and if you can't, `throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", e);`.
4. Note that storing security credentials in raw text in files is not an appropriate security measure. If a company would store such data like that today, and due to some leak that data gets out, and you do business in europe, big fines. GDPR demands industry standard protocols. You should take the security credentials and hash them using a hash algorithm specifically designed for this (such as bcrypt, scrypt, or pbkdf), and store those hashes. That, or even more advanced techniques, such as PKI-based authentication.
5. You're using FileReader which is never okay, as it uses 'platform default encoding', and you never want that. Fortunately, the new file API defaults to UTF-8 which is great.
6. File.separator is solely for printing stuff to users, you do not need it in java paths; always use forward slash, java knows what it means and that works even on windows. Better yet, just construct it using e.g. the Path API.

Example of doing it better:

```
Path p = Paths.get(programPath[0], "tempDb.txt"));
try (BufferedReader br = Files.newBufferedReader(p)) {
   // read your stuff
}
```

Comment: I believe StackOverflow asks its users to be nice to newbies.

Comment: @maksimov I believe this is a nice answer, covering a lot of topics that needs covering. Which part of this very useful answer do you feel isn't nice?

Comment: @Andreas while the answer itself may well be informative, it could be less harsh: "you're writing java code as if it's still 1992", "deplorable exception handling". People come here for help, not judgements.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is more comprehensive. A likely culprit of your particular problem is:

```
if(line[0].equals(cardNr) && line[1].equals(pin)) {
    String[] loggedInAs = {line[0], line[1]};
    tempFile.createTempFile(programPath, loggedInAs);
    return true;
```

That means you will return without closing your file. If you use try with resources, that won't be a problem.

```
try(Scanner dbScanner = new Scanner(db)) {
     // TODO db open
    //now read the file line by line...
```

Now dbScanner will be closed, even if you exit the method via return, or exceptionally.

You should do that with all the objects you're closing. They're `autoclosable`

Comment: If I understood correctly: when I'm using try () functions the objects are autoclosable, right?

Comment: @n1c0t1n3 `AutoClosable` is an interface. Any class you find that derives from it is advertising: Yup, I need closing. If you feel like something is a resource, just stick it in a try-with-resources block. if it isn't, your compiler will helpfully tell you that it isn't.